# How to install Ubuntu Server 12.10 on Proliant Microserver?

Tags: installation, server, lvm

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 12.10 on my Proliant Microserver N40L but I am having problems.

I want to install it on the 5th drive, connected to the 5th Sata port. Everything seems fine until I reboot to start the OS... which doesn't happen.

The hard drive is seen as `/dev/sde`, `sda` to `sdd` are the data drives and I do not want to touch them.

I am not sure if the problem is due to `grub` or if I am choosing the right partitioning mode (tried LVM, full disk, etc)

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the boot order on the bios? It's probably trying to boot from the first hard-drive instead of the fifth.